# I want to check if process is in ideal state or not

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to check does msiexec is in the ideal state or in stop state. How to check it with powershell?

Comment: By `ideal` state you mean 'Running'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$chk = Get-Process -Name msiexec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($chk -eq $null)
{ 
  # Here goes the statements which will be executed if the process msiexec is not running / stopped
}
else
{
  # Here goes the statements which will be executed if the process msiexec is running / ideal state
}
```